# SQL Server 2012 installation shared feature directory and instance root directory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

During installation, is it ok to choose different Drives (say D and E) for `Installation shared feature directory` and `Instance root directory` or they should be on the same drive, or should any of them be on the OS drive (usually C)?

**UPDATE**: OR, what in fact is the best practice?

Comment: I suppose if it wasn't OK to do it then Microsoft wouldn't have provided those options in the installer. If you're asking what's best practice, that's a different question.

Comment: @joeqwerty Good comment. I've added an **UPDATE**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your server, how much disk space you have, how fast your disks are on the different drives, etc.  Most people prefer to not have some features on the drive with the operating system and the pagefile.  Back in the day, poorly behaved SQL databases would happily overwrite the operating system if they grew too large, as a colleague discovered back around SQL Server 7.  I've been nervous about databases on the system drive ever since.

Anyway, I think [this answer from dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28561/24080) might prove useful to you, but I don't think the world will end if you do or don't split the shared features and instance directories onto different drives.  It depends a lot on your hardware, how you're using SQL Server, etc.